# How do I subscribe to supplementary server channel to install sun jdk 6 on RHEL 4.x

Tags: linux, installation, java, redhat, sun

I want to install sun jdk 6 on RHEL 4.x using 
`yum install java-1.6.0-sun-devel` but found that I have to subscribe to supplementary server channel. How do I do that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

Add the supplementary channel/repository:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-6-server-supplementary
```

Check that the needed package is available and install:

```
yum list *-sun-devel
yum install java-1.6.0-sun-devel
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer has been downvoted. I rechecked and it still works. Obviously, you need to be root or have sudo rights to run these commands, maybe the downvoter didn't have those.